# need to remove the last zeros in line

Tags: shell

need to read a file. check for the zeros in the last of each line . if the last digit is zero I want to delete it .please help me for this

```
input="temp.txt"
while IFS= read -r line
do 
echo "output    :$line"



if [[ $line == 0$ ]]; then
  echo " blash "
  else
    echo "anotherblash"
  fi

done < "$input"
```

Comment: To delete all lines which end in `0`, simply use `grep -v '0$' "$input"`

Comment: If the comment by @John1024 isn't what you are looking for, then perhaps provide an example of the temp.txt and your desired output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this type of substitution with sed:

```
sed 's/0*$//' temp.txt
```

This removes all the trailing zeros from each line. `0*` matches "zero or more" 0s, and `$` matches the end of the line.

If you only ever want to remove one 0, then remove the `*`.

If you prefer to do the same thing in the shell (I assume you use bash, since your attempt includes `[[`), you could do this:

```
#!/bin/bash

# match any line ending in one or more zeros
# capture everything up to the trailing 0s
re='(.*[^0])0+$'

while read -r line; do
  # use =~ for regex match
  if [[ $line =~ $re ]]; then
    # assign first capture group, discarding trailing 0s
    line=${BASH_REMATCH[1]}
  fi
  echo "$line"
done < temp.txt
```

But this approach has the disadvantages of being more complicated and less portable, so I would go with the sed option.

Answer (score 1):

In the expression command `[[ $line == 0$ ]]` you use the regular expression `0$`, but, as `man sh` tells:

> When the == and != operators are used, the string to  the  right
>                 of the operator is considered a pattern and matched according to
>                 the rules described below under **Pattern Matching**. …
>
> An  additional  binary operator, =~, is available, with the same
>                 precedence as == and !=.  When it is used,  the  string  to  the
>                 right  of the operator is considered an extended regular expres-
>                 sion and matched accordingly (as in regex(3)).

So, since you use the `==` operator, you have to specify a pattern as with *filename matching*, i. e. `[[ $line == *0 ]]`.

Comment: Yes, that's true, but how do you remove the zeros? Also, it looks likes the excerpt is from `man bash` rather than `man sh` (I guess that `sh` may point to bash on your system).

Comment: @Tom Fenech - This question has been answered by you. ;-)

Comment: @Tom Fenech - Regarding `bash`, you're right, but for an unknown shell, the used `[[` may not exist at all, so I think `bash` is a good guess.

Answer (score 1):

While the solution given by John1024 in the comment is the right way to go, if you prefer to follow your original approach, it does not make sense to compare `[[  $line == 0$ ]]`, because this would just check whether the line consists of the digit zero, forllowed by a dollar sign. Instead, you would have to do a *regular expression match*, i.e.

```
if [[ $line =~ 0$ ]]
```

This would yield true, if the line ends in a zero.

Another possibility is to stick with globbing and write the condition as

```
if [[ $line == *0 ]]
```

Note that within [[ ... ]], a =~ does regexp matching and a == does wildcard matching (i.e. via globbing).